# Why can't I see the OS disk I just attached?

Tags: azure

I just added a disk to my vm in azure :

[image]

But when I connect to my server and do a df -h I don't see it. Should I mount something to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

> But when I connect to my server and do a df -h I don't see it. Should I mount something to make it work ?

Yes. You need to format the disk with **mkfs** and then mount the disk with **mount**.

**df** only list the amount of available disk space used by file system. But a new added disk doesn't have a file system.

To check the disk information, please use **fdisk -l**.

Note: All of these commands need the privilege of root.